# Comparison and maximum principle for parabolic pde

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I was told the comparison principle can also be understood as the fact that the difference between a subsolution and a supersolution satisfies the maximum principle. I also know comparison principle can be regarded as the nonlinear version of maximum principle. I am vague about distinguishing these two theorem in a precise manner. Here is a version of weak MP from Evans p.368

Assume $u\in C^{(2,1)}(\Omega_T)\cap C(\bar{\Omega}_T)$ and 
\begin{equation}
 c\equiv 0\quad\text{in }\Omega_T
\end{equation}

If
    \begin{equation}%\label{subconw1}
  u_t+Lu\le 0\quad\text{in }\Omega_T
 \end{equation}
    then
    \begin{equation*}  \max_{\substack{\bar{\Omega}_T}}u=\max_{\substack{\bar{\Gamma}_T}}u
 \end{equation*}
 Likewise, if
    \begin{equation}%\label{supconw1}
  u_t+Lu\ge 0\quad\text{in }\Omega_T
 \end{equation}
    then
    \begin{equation*}
\min_{\substack{\bar{\Omega}_T}}u=\min_{\substack{\bar{\Gamma}_T}}u  
 \end{equation*}

I would like a comparison principle theorem by modifying above. Please help!
(This is what I know 
https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Comparison_principle#Parabolic_case
)